Unable to verify using phpseclib version3
I am trying to verify the signature of my payload using phpseclib v3 but unable to do so
Encryption on node.js
    var express = require('express');
    const crypto = require("crypto")
    var app = express();
    const privateKey = `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
    XXXXX
    -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`;
    function generateDigitalSignature(data) {
     const sign = crypto.createSign('RSA-SHA256');
     sign.update(data);
    return sign.sign(privateKey, 'base64');
   }
  const signature = generateDigitalSignature('test data');
  console.log('Generated Signature:', signature);

In my PHP code I'm trying to verify the signature but it fails.
PHP Code:
use phpseclib3\Crypt\RSA;
use phpseclib3\Crypt\PublicKeyLoader;
$publicKey = '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
XXXXX
        -----END PUBLIC KEY-----'; 
$message = 'test data';
$key = PublicKeyLoader::load($publicKey, $password = false);
$result = $key->verify($message, base64_decode($signature));
 var_dump($result);

In my node js , I can sign and verify like wise i can do the same in php side using phpseclib v3 However when i sign using nodejs script and verify using php, I am not able to do that.

RSA-SHA256 specifies PKCS#1 v1.5 padding, while phpseclib v3 defaults to PSS padding, so you need to explicitly set PKCS#1 v1.5 padding with $key->withPadding(RSA::SIGNATURE_PKCS1)->verify... (the digest is SHA256 by default), s. here.
